# Throw 404 in c# to go to customerror.aspx without 302 and 301

Tags: c#, .net, httpexception

I have custom errors set in web.config for a 404 error and in IIS.
My custom error page works ok.

I want to be able to go to my custom error page from a page load event.

If I throw a 404 using

```
throw new HttpException(404, "Not found");
```

I get to the custom error page but looking at the responses I get a 302 found and a 301 permanent redirect then a 404 generated.

How can I remove the 302 and 301?

I have tried Response.Clear() before throwing the exception and also Response.StatusCode=404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default when there's an HTTP error IIS will redirect with a 302 to the error page.
You can tell IIS to instead rewrite the response with the defined error page in the web.config :
With the customErrors tag :

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
        <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error404.aspx"/>
    </customErrors>
</system.web>
```

This works only with aspx pages, not with ASP.NET MVC

with the httpErrors tag :

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
        <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
        <error statusCode="404" path="/Error404.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
    </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

With httpErrors you can't use ~/ to reference the root of the application, but it'll work with / if your application is not hosted as a sub application in IIS

Comment: The problem is that the defined error page is at the web root and the page where I'm raising the error is often one or two directory levels lower. The result is that the script links are not valid. Cant use ~/ in the path as they are not asp runat server objects.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem, you don't use web.config to define your error pages? because with a page Error404.aspx at the root of the application, <error statusCode="404" redirect="Error404.aspx"/>
would work from any sublevel page

Comment: Thank you for your help. I currently have the custom error defined in web.config <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/pagenotfound404.aspx"/> and inthe IIS <system.web><httpErrors><error statusCode="404" path="~/pagenotfound404.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>

Comment: It seems to be working now in that the error page is rendering ok. Still get the 302 and 301 before the 404. Perhaps this doesnt matter.

Comment: Ok I understand now, you are using the httpErrors tag, my answer was for the customErrors tag. I updated my answer to include the solution with httpErrors.